# Does single hive application(job) spawn multiple yarn applications?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

Does a single HIVE query that gets submitted to Yarn creates multiple jobs (i.e. multiple YARN applications) ? Here I treat job and application to be the same think in YARN context.

From what I understand -- Yarn creates an Application Master (AM) per 'application'. So here that single HIVE query can be treated as an 'application'. So, the Resource Manager will create container on some node and start AM in that container. That container in turn may create multiple 'tasks' (not applications) i.e. mappers and reducers within other containers reserved for that AM (on the same or different node -- this is immaterial here). Now the collection of all these Application Masters are engaged in solving that single HIVE query that is submitted to YARN. In fact that's why we say that AM is per application. Since we submitted just one HIVE query, from YARN point of view there is only one application. So when I fire the below YARN command, it should show me just one application running:-

```
yarn application -list
```

Is this understanding correct? Or that if we have several mappers and reducers spawned for that one HIVE query, multiple YARN applications are invoked?

Comment: Start the Hive CLI, run a query, and observe the logs. After Hive has compiled the execution plan, it spawns a YARN job, and you will see the one and only "application_id" of your query displayed in plain sight.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are running Hive-on-**TEZ** then it's a little bit different -- TEZ has a "keep alive" feature to re-use the same YARN AM for multiple queries, requesting or releasing new containers dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were correct in the beginning:

- A YARN application created by MapReduce is called a Job. So **application = job**. Correct.
- There is one AM per job. Correct.

From there, the things you said get a bit mixed up. A Hive query is not an application. A Hive query is translated by Hive into chained MapReduce jobs. So when you execute a complicated Hive Query, Hive will submit the necessary MapReduce jobs (which are YARN applications), running one after the other to obtain your final result.

For example, let's take the following SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(total) as sumtotal, city
FROM donations
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY sumtotal;
```

If you want to manually solve this with MapReduce, you need to create 2 jobs:

- Job 1 - Aggregation: Map input to (city,total) pairs and reduce get the SUM value per city
- Job 2 - Sorting: Map the result of Job 1 to inversed pairs (total,city) and let the shuffle/reduce sort them

Detailed explanation and illustration on how to solve this with MR jobs [here](http://blog.ditullio.fr/2015/12/24/hadoop-basics-filter-aggregate-sort-mapreduce/).

If you run that query in Hive, the output looks like this:

```
INFO  : number of splits:3
INFO  : Submitting tokens for job: job_1454508485700_0039
INFO  : The url to track the job: http://ubuntu0:8088/proxy/application_1454508485700_0039/
INFO  : Starting Job = job_1454508485700_0039, Tracking URL = http://ubuntu0:8088/proxy/application_1454508485700_0039/
INFO  : Kill Command = /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1454508485700_0039
INFO  : Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 3; number of reducers: 3
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:21:15,773 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:08,421 Stage-1 map = 11%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 99.2 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:17,019 Stage-1 map = 44%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 127.32 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:20,694 Stage-1 map = 67%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 134.32 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:21,906 Stage-1 map = 78%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 135.2 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:32,877 Stage-1 map = 89%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 147.49 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:35,379 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 149.85 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:39,108 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 44%, Cumulative CPU 160.65 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:41,578 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 56%, Cumulative CPU 170.0 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:42,792 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 60%, Cumulative CPU 171.87 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:44,022 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 89%, Cumulative CPU 183.23 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:22:46,540 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 183.23 sec
INFO  : Ended Job = job_1454508485700_0039
INFO  : number of splits:2
INFO  : Submitting tokens for job: job_1454508485700_0040
INFO  : The url to track the job: http://ubuntu0:8088/proxy/application_1454508485700_0040/
INFO  : Starting Job = job_1454508485700_0040, Tracking URL = http://ubuntu0:8088/proxy/application_1454508485700_0040/
INFO  : Kill Command = /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1454508485700_0040
INFO  : Hadoop job information for Stage-2: number of mappers: 2; number of reducers: 1
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:23:16,180 Stage-2 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:23:46,453 Stage-2 map = 50%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 13.39 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:23:47,715 Stage-2 map = 67%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 14.73 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:23:48,945 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 17.38 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:24:10,960 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 71%, Cumulative CPU 25.33 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:24:13,383 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 98%, Cumulative CPU 31.32 sec
INFO  : 2016-02-10 22:24:14,616 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 32.61 sec
INFO  : MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 32 seconds 610 msec
INFO  : Ended Job = job_1454508485700_0040
INFO  : Moving data to: /user/hduser/donors/hive_output_part2 from hdfs://ubuntu0:9000/user/hive/warehouse/.hive-staging_hive_2016-02-10_22-20-50_281_4971139345555329337-4/-ext-10001
INFO  : Table default.hive_output_part2 stats: [numFiles=0, numRows=14966, totalSize=0, rawDataSize=321343]
No rows affected (207.86 seconds)
```

You can see that Hive created 2 jobs as well, one after the other. You can see "Starting Job" logged twice, as well as new job urls generated twice.

Hive refers to the jobs as "Stages" but these are just normal MapReduce jobs (i.e. applications).

You can find comparisons and benchmarks of Hive vs some manual jobs I did [here](http://blog.ditullio.fr/2016/02/11/hadoop-basics-running-sql-queries-with-hive/#Query_from_Part_II_AggregatingSorting). Hive used the same number of jobs and has roughly the same execution times as my hand-coded MR jobs. So basically its still chained MapReduce jobs, which are generated for you so that you dont need to write code.

Everything I said is valid only for the default execution engine, MapReduce. Using Tez or Spark as the execution engine is a different story.